# Strange behaviour when laying out subviews

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I am creating a UI that the user can page through multiple views by using a UIScrollView. I create the UIView objects in code and add them to UIScrollView. I use the code below to create the views.

```
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

UIView *brandView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 50.0, frame.size.width, 30)];
label.text = [brand objectForKey:@"name"];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[brandView addSubview:label];

UIImageView *logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
logoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 100.0, 280.0, 300.0);
[brandView addSubview:logoImageView];
logoImageView.file = [brand objectForKey:@"logo"];
[logoImageView loadInBackground];
```

Although I give 50.0 for the y coordinate for the label, I can't see the label at all when I run the app. And logoImageView has 100.0 for its top but it appears just below the status bar, as if it had 0.0 for it's y coordinate.

What is the reason for this strange behaviour, am I doing something wrong?

Note: Auto layout for the UIScrollView is disabled on IB.

Comment: What are you passing in for frame in brandView's initWithFrame:?

Comment: @rdelmar I updated the code in the question.

Comment: I copied your code, and it worked OK for me. What size is your scroll view? I made mine the same size as the screen.

Comment: Scroll view is the same size with the screen except navbar.

Comment: It seems like I did pretty much the same as you, so I'm at a loss as to why yours doesn't work. Can you post your project somewhere that I could look at it?

Comment: I have replicated the issue, when I gave like this UIView *brandView = [[UIView alloc] init]; it got worked for me.. Please find my answer below...

Comment: Confirm frame with `NSLog(@"frame=%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.scrollView.frame));` If calling your code from this from `viewDidLoad`, try deferring this until `viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will work for you !

```
CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * 10;
frame.origin.y = 0;
frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

UIView *brandView = [[UIView alloc] init]; // CHANGE THAT HAS TO BE DONE

UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 50.0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, 30)];
label.text = @"Test";
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; // DEPRECATED IN iOS 6.0
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[brandView addSubview:label];
[self.scrollView addSubview:brandView];
```